# Open CSV file with pandas python with quotations and numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to open a csv file with the following data:

```
Customer code,Longitude,Latitude,Address,Beg_timeslot,End_timeslot,Service time,Demand,Frequency
0,4.4231505,51.9316558,"Keenstraat 8, Rotterdam",0,28800,0,0.0,
07-02,4.3134819,51.9038268,"Edisonstraat 9-11, VLAARDINGEN",0,28800,90,1000.0,Weekly
```

I'm using the following code:

```
locations_dataset = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(tmp_job_path, "locations.csv"))
```

So, nothing complex in here, but for some reason I'm getting the following results:

[image: locations_dataset screenshot]

Can someone help me with this? I think it had something to do with the quotations marks. However, I cannot find the answer that works for me on stackoverflow...

Comment: The basic `pd.read_csv` works for that sample you supplied

Comment: I suspect your locale may specify `;` as list delimiter. Try `sep=","` in your call to ` read_csv`.